# Architecture that can optimize tail calls for C#

Tags: c#, tail-call-optimization

Reading a [blog entry by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx), I came across this snippet:

> ...you're going to either loop forever (if you're **on an architecture
>   that can optimize tail calls**) or run out of stack and crash the
>   process.

I'm aware that a [compiler can optimize tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Implementation_methods), but what does **an architecture that can optimize tail calls** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the .NET JIT on x64 behaves differently to the JIT on x86 - the x64 one applies tail call optimizations much more aggressively.

See this [blog post from 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx) and [this one from 2009](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx) for some implementation details (*not* to be depended upon) for some of the rules that are followed.

Comment: Not to mention different CLRs, like Mono, Rotor, Silverlight, or Windows Phone.